# Webpack is not working with Typescript aliases

Tags: typescript, webpack, alias

I have this `webpack.config.js`:

```js
{
    target: 'node',
    mode: 'production',
    // devtool: 'source-map',
    entry: {
        index: './source/lib/index.ts',
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'source'),
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'ts-loader',
                        options: {
                            compiler: 'ttypescript'
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new BundleDeclarationsWebpackPlugin({
            entry: "./source/lib/index.ts",
            outFile: "./index.d.ts"
        })
    ],
    externals: [nodeExternals()],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'bundled', 'lib'),
        filename: 'index.js',
        library: 'mongo-cleaner',
        libraryTarget: 'umd',
        globalObject: 'this',
        umdNamedDefine: true,
    }
}
```

In that you can see that I am bundling a library with webpack, keeping the node_modules as externals.

And this `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "ES5",
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "lib": [
            "ES2021"
        ],
        "outDir": "../dist",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declaration": true,
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "@/*": [
                "./lib/*"
            ],
            "@lib/*": [
                "./lib/*"
            ],
            "@bin/*": [
                "./bin/*"
            ]
        }
    },
    "plugins": [
        {
            "transform": "typescript-transform-paths"
        },
        {
            "transform": "typescript-transform-paths",
            "afterDeclarations": true
        }
    ],
    "include": [
        "lib",
        "bin"
    ]
}
```

When I do `tsc -p source` everything works, even if I have "@" paths in my requires

But when I do the same with webpack, I obtain these errors:

```
ERROR in ./source/lib/index.ts 50:16-42
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@/utils/cleaner' in '/home/euber/Github/mongo-cleaner/source/lib'

ERROR in ./source/lib/index.ts 51:19-48
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@/utils/askConfirm' in '/home/euber/Github/mongo-cleaner/source/lib'

ERROR in ./source/lib/index.ts 52:16-42
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@/utils/options' in '/home/euber/Github/mongo-cleaner/source/lib'

ERROR in ./source/lib/index.ts 53:13-45
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@/interfaces/exported' in '/home/euber/Github/mongo-cleaner/source/lib'

ERROR in ./source/lib/index.ts 54:13-32
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@/errors' in '/home/euber/Github/mongo-cleaner/source/lib'
```

How is it possible that webpack is ignoring the @?

To have more information and be able to reproduce it, just look at [this repo](https://github.com/euberdeveloper/mongo-cleaner/tree/d48cc3fd73907c35fa36f811184774b0be7b2750)

**UPDATE:**

I have tried also this answer, but it does not work:

`webpack.config.js`

```js
alias: {
            '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'lib'),
            '@lib': path.resolve(__dirname, 'lib'),
            '@bin': path.resolve(__dirname, 'bin')
        }
```

Errors:

```
ERROR in ./source/lib/index.ts 50:16-42
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@/utils/cleaner' in '/home/euber/Github/mongo-cleaner/source/lib'

ERROR in ./source/lib/index.ts 51:19-48
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@/utils/askConfirm' in '/home/euber/Github/mongo-cleaner/source/lib'

ERROR in ./source/lib/index.ts 52:16-42
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@/utils/options' in '/home/euber/Github/mongo-cleaner/source/lib'

ERROR in ./source/lib/index.ts 53:13-45
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@/interfaces/exported' in '/home/euber/Github/mongo-cleaner/source/lib'

ERROR in ./source/lib/index.ts 54:13-32
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@/errors' in '/home/euber/Github/mongo-cleaner/source/lib'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Mikhail Sereniti 's answer would work, but a module allows this to be handled automatically.

I added this:

```js
plugins: [new TsconfigPathsPlugin({
  configFile: './source/tsconfig.json',
  extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
})]
```

And it worked.

The full code:

```js
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
const BundleDeclarationsWebpackPlugin = require('bundle-declarations-webpack-plugin');
const TsconfigPathsPlugin = require('tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin');


const libConfig = {
    target: 'node',
    mode: 'production',
    // devtool: 'source-map',
    entry: {
        index: './source/lib/index.ts',
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
        plugins: [new TsconfigPathsPlugin({
            configFile: './source/tsconfig.json',
            extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
        })]
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'source'),
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'ts-loader',
                        options: {
                            compiler: 'ttypescript'
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new BundleDeclarationsWebpackPlugin({
            entry: "./source/lib/index.ts",
            outFile: "./index.d.ts"
        })
    ],
    externals: [nodeExternals()],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'bundled', 'lib'),
        filename: 'index.js',
        library: 'mongo-cleaner',
        libraryTarget: 'umd',
        globalObject: 'this',
        umdNamedDefine: true,
    }
};

const binConfig = {
    target: 'node',
    mode: 'production',
    // devtool: 'source-map',
    entry: {
        index: './source/bin/index.ts',
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
        plugins: [new TsconfigPathsPlugin({
            configFile: './source/tsconfig.json',
            extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
        })]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.BannerPlugin({ banner: '#!/usr/bin/env node', raw: true })
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts?$/,
                include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'source'),
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'ts-loader',
                        options: {
                            compiler: 'ttypescript'
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'shebang-loader'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    externals: [{
        '../lib/index': {
            amd: '../lib/index',
            root: 'mongo-cleaner',
            commonjs: '../lib/index',
            commonjs2: '../lib/index'
        },
    }, nodeExternals()],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'bundled', 'bin'),
        filename: 'index.js',
        library: 'mongo-cleaner',
        libraryTarget: 'umd',
        globalObject: 'this',
        umdNamedDefine: true,
    }
};

module.exports = [
    libConfig,
    binConfig
];
```

**EDIT:**

I found also another error. I used `ttypescript` for a similar purpose, but the "plugins" keyword should have been inside the compiler options.

So, even without the `TsconfigPathsPlugin` thing, by changing the `tsconfig.json` like this the problem was solved:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "ES5",
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "lib": [
            "ES2021"
        ],
        "outDir": "../dist",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declaration": true,
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "@/*": [
                "./lib/*"
            ],
            "@lib/*": [
                "./lib/*"
            ],
            "@bin/*": [
                "./bin/*"
            ]
        },
        "plugins": [
            {
                "transform": "typescript-transform-paths"
            },
            {
                "transform": "typescript-transform-paths",
                "afterDeclarations": true
            }
        ],
    },
    "include": [
        "lib",
        "bin"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the plugin tip. I was having a nightmare getting webpack aliasing to work. Switched to using TsconfigPathsPlugin and it all works perfectly.

Answer (score 7):

You have specified path aliases for typescript compiler but you also need to  specify [aliases for webpack](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvealias) cause webpack resolves modules in it's own way.

So you need to update webpack config is some way like in the following example:

```js
{
...
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
    alias: {
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'source/lib'),
      '@lib': path.resolve(__dirname, 'source/lib'),
      '@bin': path.resolve(__dirname, 'source/bin')
    }
  }
...
}
```

Comment: You are right, I'll also try it. But then why does this work even without those aliases https://github.com/euberdeveloper/euberlog/blob/main/webpack.config.js?

Comment: I've tried your solution but the error remain the same

Comment: You got the same error because information you provided in question was a bit wrong. I took a look into the repo and found that tsconfig and webpack config are placed in different directories. So I updated resolving paths in my code snippet to match your repo specifity. Tested in your repo – it works.

Comment: Ok, I think that your answer deserves the bounty, while the one I wrote is more thorough, so I will give you the bounty when it is possible, while accepting my answer